# Designing full screen graphics for different Android devices

Tags: android

I am a experienced iOS developer but I am totally new to Android. I have to develop a Android app with a full screen background image and various images that has to fit the screen quite well. Now on iOS we live in a "protected" world where this is easy as I know the screen size of every device, but on Android that is very different I think. I have read about the small/normal/large/xlarge and ldpi/mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi structure, but I cant find anything on designing a full screen image that works well across devices with different sizes and ratios. How would I go and do that? I mean, what image size should I make for e.g. a normal+hdpi device to make it look good? The images must not be distorted (so the ratio must not be changed) but I can live with them being shrinked in size. Should I add some "space" to the image in top/bottom or sides to make it work well? How is this done best?

Thank you

Søren

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232322/graphic-dimensions-for-hdpi-ldpi-mdpi - try checking this out.. you do the math

Comment: A big list of screen sizes and dimensions as well as pixel density: http://www.emirweb.com/ScreenDeviceStatistics.php#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do all the scaling myself. Use as little xml as possible and set all the sizes within your app once you have the screen dimensions that you were given by android.

Comment: Sounds like the way to go for me, but what (max) size should my full screen background image be? I am only targeting phones, not tablets. Is there a list with different device screen sizes and how common they are?

Comment: rule of thumb, take the biggest device that you want to support and make the image 50% bigger. So Samsung Note 2 should be the biggest semi-phone screen available and to support future devices you should expect an increase in size. I know the image will be HUGE then but... comes with the territory