# Creating XHDPI, HDPI, MDPI, LDPI images in Photoshop for Android

Tags: android, image, resize, photoshop

When we are making images for android app, I wanted to know which way is correct for making **XHDPI**, **HDPI**, **MDPI**, **LDPI**. (both may be wrong)

**The first way** is get the original image, open in photoshop, change the DPI to 320 (the original has 326 DPI) then save the image as XHDPI, then change the DPI to 240 for HDPI, 160 for MDPI, 120 for LDPI.

**Second way**, open the original image, then half the image size (without changing the DPI) and that would be MDPI, resize the image to 0.75 of MDPI's size and that would be LDPI, resize it to 1.5 of MDPI's size and that would be HDPI.

So basically, first way is change the DPI and photoshop automatically resizes the image, the second way is keep the dpi same and manually resize the image.

If both ways are wrong, please let me know the correct way to create these images in photoshop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Graphic dimensions for hdpi/ldpi/mdpi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232322/graphic-dimensions-for-hdpi-ldpi-mdpi)

Comment: possible duplicate yadda yadda, but this question helped me clear some things out. Stackoverflow should rethink some policies..

Comment: This doesn't look like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8232322/238886 .  That question is about what size to make images; this question is about how to get them to that size.

Answer (score 19):

Sorry, i'm a little bit late but this can help other people too.

I use the free plugin ["Cut&Slice me"](http://www.cutandslice.me/).
It's very easy to use.

Just click on the layer you want to export and the plugin automatically create folders (drawable-xhdpi, drawable-hdpi...) and put them on.

I hope this can help you ;)

Comment: For any future readers, this plugin has stopped working for  Photoshop CC 2014 as Adobe has dropped Flash Panels.

Comment: According to the website it seems to be planned to create a new version of "Cut&Slice me" that supports Photoshop CC 2014.

Comment: Also this does not support xxxhdpi, ldpi or tvdpi

Comment: I think, this is nice
https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/export-to-android-photoshop-script

Answer (score 4):

I guess you can use the [asset studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) webapp instead. It's really convenient.

Choose the option you need depending on the use you are going to give to the icons (it's not the same a notification icon than a launcher icon, for instance).

Comment: [With a workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754523/is-there-any-tool-which-can-a-resize-png-image-into-a-image-for-ldpi-mdpi-hdp#comment43607718_10754563), you can use the Generic Icon Generator of Android Asset Studio to generate images of all sizes.

Comment: @Adam this will always create a square image