# Scaling images for various resolutions on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

In the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources) it's suggested that images should be scaled using the 3:4:6:8 scaling ratio, from ldpi to xhdpi.

And [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232322/graphic-dimensions-for-hdpi-ldpi-mdpi) suggest that this has been expanded with 12 when xxhdpi was announced, so that the scaling ratio is 3:4:6:8:12 from ldpi to xxhdpi.

So accordingly this would be how you would scale graphics for Android:

[image]

Just want to be 100% sure that this is the correct way to scale on Android? It's puzzling to me that you have scale by different factors.

Comment: You are correct, and I see this becoming a real issue for me in the near future. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that's correct. Note that if you go 2 steps, you will always have a scaling factor of 2. The reason for different factors is to make the factors in between nice rational numbers.

Rational scaling factors with small numerator and denominator help to reduce scaling artifacts due to aliasing.